# Is it possible to host a ASP.NET website in a wireless adhoc network?

Tags: asp.net, networking, wireless, adhoc

I need to set up a server for testing a project. So is it possible to host it on a wireless adhoc network? 
So how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET works on top of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) which works on top of TCP. The underlying transport infrastructure does not matter.

The only requirement is the client must be able to connect to the TCP port 80 (or any of your choice) on the server.